# No service name for myRole plink

Tags: eclipse, esb, wso2, bpel, wso2-esb

When im trying to run my BPEL process im landing into below error.

**No service name for myRole plink {Partner Link name}.**

> [2012-06-15 14:02:58,973] ERROR - NStateLatch - Latch error, was
>   releasing for state 1 but actually in -1 java.lang.Exception  at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.NStateLatch.release(NStateLatch.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.getEndpointToMyRoleMap(BpelProcess.java:769)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.initMyRoleMex(BpelProcess.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.createNewMyRoleMex(BpelEngineImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.createMessageExchange(BpelEngineImpl.java:153)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.createMessageExchange(BPELProcessProxy.java:269)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.onAxisServiceInvoke(BPELProcessProxy.java:148)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.handleInOutOperation(BPELMessageReceiver.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(BPELMessageReceiver.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> [2012-06-15 14:02:58,975] ERROR - BPELProcessProxy - Exception
>   occurred while invoking ODE java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   service name for myRole plink EmployeeDSPL    at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.setRoles(BpelProcess.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.access$1400(BpelProcess.java:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$HydrationLatch.doHydrate(BpelProcess.java:940)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$HydrationLatch.access$100(BpelProcess.java:836)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$HydrationLatch$2.run(BpelProcess.java:846)
>     at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.NStateLatch.latch(NStateLatch.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.getEndpointToMyRoleMap(BpelProcess.java:766)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.initMyRoleMex(BpelProcess.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.createNewMyRoleMex(BpelEngineImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.createMessageExchange(BpelEngineImpl.java:153)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.createMessageExchange(BPELProcessProxy.java:269)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.onAxisServiceInvoke(BPELProcessProxy.java:148)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.handleInOutOperation(BPELMessageReceiver.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.axis2.receivers.BPELMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(BPELMessageReceiver.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:199)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
>     at
>   org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

This is hindering.. Can any one please let me know why this comes up ?

I have the roles assigned appropriately for my partner link as shown below:

[image]

My code is also as per the UI shown

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have set a myrole for "EmployeeDSPL". But I don't see any `<receive>` activity in your process that uses this partnerlink. I think you are just trying to invoke an external partner service. In this case, you just need the partner role. Set the "My Role" to "None"

HTH

Comment: I have receive activity ... reciveInput is the one and its Partner Link is "client" and im using EmployeeDSPL to call another external service,

Comment: It should work if you set the myrole of EmployeeDSPL to none. please attach the BPEL file and the deploy.xml